# Redirect input from multiple scripts over ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, redirection

I have this working command in the terminal (bare in mind the ssh to localhost is for testing - makes no difference if it's a remote server or not):

```
> ssh nick@127.0.0.1 sh -s -- < "./a.sh" < "./b.sh"
```

a.sh:

```
export var="hey world"
```

b.sh:

```
echo "$var"
```

prints "hey world" as expected.

But when I add the same command into a script file as such (let's say it's named `run.sh`):

```
#!/bin/sh

# ...
ssh nick@127.0.0.1 sh -s -- < "./a.sh" < "./b.sh"
```

and I execute as follows:

```
chmod +x ./run.sh
./run.sh
```

it doesn't work - a blank line is printed. I've tested other commands and they similarly do not appear to have been read.

What's going on?

---

EDIT: I sohuld have clarified, I have solved the issue in itself with the same answer Cornholio came to, but I want to know precisely what is causing it to work via REPL vs in a shell script file

Answer (score 1):

You're probably using a shell different from `/bin/sh` for your command line test. Your problem is redirection support in `/bin/sh`. I've found no way to append the contents of two files to `stdin`. To see what's happening you can replace the `ssh` command with `cat`:

```
> cat < "./a.sh" < "./b.sh"
echo "$var"

> cat < "./a.sh" 
export var="hey world"

> cat < "./b.sh" 
echo "$var"
```

How about `cat a.sh b.sh ... | ssh nick@127.0.0.1`?

Comment: I should have mentioned that I did use this exact `cat` solution! But I'm more interested in why it isn't working...

Comment: Good job as a solution the problem though! Have a +1 :)

Comment: I'd say you're using different shells ... not sure which is your command line but the script is `/bin/sh`. My bash also has problems with multiple redirects.

Comment: Ah, you're right. I'm using zsh :) Add that to the answer and I'll accept!